# Nginx upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response from upstream

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, server

I understand that there are many threads similar to this issue however the solutions do not work for me.

This route is responsible for running a function that returns a JSON response however seemingly when the data being returned is too large it runs into the error ***upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream***.

The route however, works fine when executed on local host or if the parameter in the route is for a different user where there is less data involved.

I have tried changing the php ini settings on the server as well as adjusting the fast_cgi and client settings but all to no avail.

Can someone guide me in the right direction please.

Error Message ->  **upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream**

php ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 400M
post_max_size = 400M
```

nginx conf

```
client_max_body_size 200m;
client_body_timeout 2024;
client_header_timeout 2024;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        include fastcgi_params;
 }
```

Comment: It might be `content-length` header issue - if it's set make sure it's correct.